# ZXing, Android, JetPack Compose - Draw Bounding Box Around QR Code

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, zxing, jetpack

I am building a QR code scanner using Jetpack Compose in Android. The scanning part and reading the bit values in the QR code work great and as expected. However, as a part of my prototype, I want to be able to draw a red box around the QR code.

Currently, I am dealing with two issues. The height of the red box appears to be correct, but the width is too small and I am not sure why. The second problem is that as I move my phone, the bounding box appears to go all over the place and not locked on the actual QR code. I'm not sure how to fix this.

[image: The bounding box doesn't seem to be the right size and it does not align with the QR code unless the angle is perfect.]

Here is my `CameraView` composable function...

```kotlin
@Composable
fun CameraPreview() {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val scanner = MultiFormatReader().apply {
        val hints: MutableMap<DecodeHintType, Any> = EnumMap(DecodeHintType::class.java)
        hints[DecodeHintType.POSSIBLE_FORMATS] = listOf(BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE)
        setHints(hints)
    }

    val qrCodeBounds = remember { mutableStateOf<Rect?>(null) }

    BoxWithConstraints(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        val screenWidth = maxWidth
        val scanBoxSize = screenWidth * 0.6f // adjust the size of the scanning area here

        AndroidView(
            factory = { ctx ->
                val previewView = PreviewView(ctx)
                val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(ctx)
                cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
                    val cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
                    val preview = Preview.Builder().build().also {
                        it.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.surfaceProvider)
                    }
                    val imageAnalysis = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                        .build()
                        .also {
                            it.setAnalyzer(ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(ctx)) { imageProxy ->
                                val result = scanQRCode(imageProxy, scanner)
                                imageProxy.close()
                                if (result != null) {
                                    println("QR Code found: ${result.text}")
                                    println("Image Proxy Width: ${imageProxy.width}, Height: ${imageProxy.height}")
                                    qrCodeBounds.value = getBoundingBox(result.resultPoints, imageProxy.width, imageProxy.height, previewView.width, previewView.height)
                                } else {
                                    qrCodeBounds.value = null
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    try {
                        cameraProvider.unbindAll()
                        cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                            context as ComponentActivity,
                            CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA,
                            preview,
                            imageAnalysis
                        )
                    } catch (exc: Exception) {
                        // Handle exceptions
                    }
                }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(ctx))
                previewView
            },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        )

        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .matchParentSize()
            .background(Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.8f))
        )

        // Scanning area box with a clear cutout
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(scanBoxSize)
                .align(Alignment.Center)
                .drawBehind {
                    // Draw a rounded clear rectangle to create a cutout effect
                    drawRoundRect(
                        color = Color.Transparent,
                        topLeft = Offset(0f, 0f),
                        size = Size(size.width, size.height),
                        cornerRadius = CornerRadius(x = 12.dp.toPx(), y = 12.dp.toPx()),
                        blendMode = BlendMode.Clear
                    )
                }
                .border(2.dp, MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary, RoundedCornerShape(12.dp))
        )

        qrCodeBounds.value?.let { bounds ->
            Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                drawRect(
                    color = Color.Red,
                    topLeft = Offset(bounds.left.toFloat(), bounds.top.toFloat()),
                    size = Size(bounds.width().toFloat(), bounds.height().toFloat()),
                    style = Stroke(width = 3.dp.toPx())
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my `getBoundingBox` function

```kotlin
private fun getBoundingBox(resultPoints: Array<ResultPoint>?, imageWidth: Int, imageHeight: Int, previewWidth: Int, previewHeight: Int): Rect? {
    if (resultPoints == null || resultPoints.size != 4) {
        return null
    }

    // Calculate scale factors
    val scaleX = previewWidth.toFloat() / imageWidth
    val scaleY = previewHeight.toFloat() / imageHeight

    // Apply scale factors to the coordinates
    val left = (resultPoints[0].x * scaleX).toInt()
    val top = (resultPoints[0].y * scaleY).toInt()
    val right = (resultPoints[2].x * scaleX).toInt()
    val bottom = (resultPoints[2].y * scaleY).toInt()

    return Rect(left, top, right, bottom)
}
```

And this is my `scanQRCode` function

```kotlin
private fun scanQRCode(imageProxy: ImageProxy, scanner: MultiFormatReader): Result? {
    val data = imageProxy.planes[0].buffer.let { buffer ->
        val data = ByteArray(buffer.capacity())
        buffer.get(data)
        buffer.clear()
        data
    }
    val source = PlanarYUVLuminanceSource(
        data,
        imageProxy.width,
        imageProxy.height,
        0,
        0,
        imageProxy.width,
        imageProxy.height,
        false
    )
    val binaryBitmap = BinaryBitmap(HybridBinarizer(source))
    return try {
        scanner.decodeWithState(binaryBitmap)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        null // QR Code not found
    }
}
```